# Lua Setup error

Tags: lua, ubuntu-12.04

Hi I ve downloaded lua extracted it and tried to make it

```
sg1@kalanamith:~/lua-5.2.1$ make linux test
```

after that um getting this error

```
ar rcu liblua.a lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o     lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o     lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lbitlib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o     lstrlib.o ltablib.o loadlib.o linit.o 
ranlib liblua.a
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL -DLUA_USE_LINUX    -c -o lua.o lua.c    
gcc -o lua   lua.o liblua.a -lm -Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lncurses 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lua] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sg1/lua-5.2.1/src'
make[1]: *** [linux] Error 2   
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sg1/lua-5.2.1/src'
make: *** [linux] Error 2
```

This is my first day with Lua so Ill be great full if any one can give me a help. thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have `ncurses` installed?

Comment: 12.04 is the Linux version

Comment: eh ncursers? ill check .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `ncurses` library. Make sure you've got all dependencies installed, e.g. by using `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev` (might depend on your system/version).

Comment: Hey Thank you seems like now the Lua is compiling.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the patch used to compile the Debian/Ubuntu package:

```
Index: lua5.2-5.2.0.obsolete.0.298371916710497/src/Makefile
===================================================================
--- lua5.2-5.2.0.obsolete.0.298371916710497.orig/src/Makefile   2012-05-04 16:27:35.000000000 +0200
+++ lua5.2-5.2.0.obsolete.0.298371916710497/src/Makefile    2012-05-04 16:27:35.000000000 +0200
@@ -103,7 +103,7 @@
 generic: $(ALL)

 linux:
-   $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lncurses"
+   $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline"

 macosx:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_MACOSX" SYSLIBS="-lreadline"
```

Original source: http://patch-tracker.debian.org/patch/series/view/lua5.2/5.2.1-3/no-ncurses-dependency.patch

Cheers